# Vuejs keyup/ v-on:keyup event is not working

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I am trying to initiate a function from methods while an input is keyup, But it's not working. My codes from template are :

```
<q-input type="number" min="1" dense borderless debounce="300" class="q-ma-xs" v- 
model="invoice_product.item_qty" placeholder="quantity" filled 
@keyup="calculateLineTotal(invoice_product)" />
```

My method :

```
<script>
   export default {
      setup() {
        return {
           invoice_product: {
             item_qty: ''
           }
        }
      },
      methods: {
         calculateLineTotal(invoice_product) {
           alert(invoice_product.item_qty)
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

I also tried with v-on:keyup

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`You can use watch property using your v model variable and there you can write your logic.
When your model value change it will called watch property

```
watch:{
 “Variable” : function(val) {
   //method 
 }
}
```